# proof that $\forall \epsilon > 0 |x - y| < \epsilon \implies y - \epsilon < x < y + \epsilon$ (Tao Analysis 1 Exercise 5.4.6)

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I am currently reading through Analysis 1, and while checking the solutions to Exercise 5.4.6 (Which is detailed below) online I found that they are different from my own, which makes me think that mine might be wrong.

> Exercise 5.4.6: Let $x, y$ be real numbers and let $\epsilon > 0$ be a
> positive real. Show that $|x − y| < \epsilon$ if and only if $y −
>  \epsilon < x < y + \epsilon$, and that $|x − y| ≤ \epsilon$ if and
> only if $y − \epsilon ≤ x ≤ y + \epsilon$.

**proof:** lets start by assuming that $|x − y| < \epsilon$.

Lets also assume that $x = y - \epsilon - \Delta = y - (\epsilon + \Delta)$, for some $\Delta \geq 0$. one can easily show that $x \leq y - \epsilon$.

now we'll show the following: $|x - y| < \epsilon \implies |y - (\epsilon + \Delta) - y| < \epsilon \implies |-(\epsilon + \Delta)| < \epsilon \implies \Delta < 0$.

We arrived to the conclusion that $\Delta < 0$, but we also know that $\Delta > 0$, which is impossible by the trichotomy of order on the real numbers. thus, $x$ has to be bigger than $y -\epsilon$. We can use the same argument when setting $x = y + \epsilon + \Delta$ in order to arrive to the conclusion that $x$ has to be smaller than $y + \epsilon$. thus, we complete the proof.

If we want to address the second part of the question, we can use the same argument to show that $\Delta \leq 0 \land \Delta \geq 0$, which implies that in addition to the result described above ($y − \epsilon < x < y + \epsilon$), $x = y \pm (\epsilon + \Delta) \iff \Delta = 0$. Thus, $y − \epsilon \leq x \leq y + \epsilon$.

Is there anything wrong with my proof?

Comment: Another way: Suppose that $|x-y|<\varepsilon$ for some $\varepsilon>0$. If $x\geq y$, then $$y-\varepsilon<y\le x=y+|x-y|<y+\varepsilon.$$ Treat $x\le y$ analogously.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch This is the answer that I found online, but I wanted to know whether my way is also correct.

Comment: also, all of the downvoters, could you explain why you downvoted? Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Your proof seems formally correct. But introducing $\Delta$ makes it more complicated than it needs to be. (Also there was only one downvoter, I have upvoted your question to undo the effect because I disagree with the downvote.)

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch I see. I'll try to rely on external (added) variable less next time. If you want, you can post everything you said as an answer and I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: @javajav I also upvoted, because you showed good work.  I don't know why anyone chose to downvote.  I regard your attempt (valid or not) to find an alternative approach as very positive.  To me, the fact that (ultimately) your introduction of $\Delta$ provides an avoidable complication is totally irrelevant.  Going down an unfamiliar path in math is often like that.